# Cross site request forgeries (CSRF) check in Laravel for Mobile devices

Tags: php, android, laravel, csrf

We're using Laravel and for signups we've enabled the [Laravel CSRF forgery checks](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#csrf-protection).

It seems to be working fine for the most part but I'm looking in our error logs and there were 5 or 6 users denied in the last 24 hours, all unique. When I look at their user agents, I can see that they're either iPhone or Android users. Is there a problem in the Laravel code? Is it possible that their IPs are getting changed and therefore are failing the CSRF check?